# How do I find parameter values from EntityQuery<T> class?

Tags: seam, jsf-1.2

I have a seam 2.2 app.  Basically I have a form with about 30 input fields.  Each field is backed by a property is SearchForm.java.  When I click "Submit" I invoke DevicesList.java (implements EntityQuery) and jump to /DevicesList.xhtml.  All the input fields and properties correspond to parameters listed DevicesList.page.xml.

In other words in DevicesList.page.xml we have

```
<param name="hostname" value="#{searchForm.devName}"/>
<param name="loopback" value="#{searchForm.devIp}"/>
<param name="platform" value="#{searchForm.platform}"/>
```

etc.

I am heavily customizing getEjbql() based on which searchForm properties are set. I have been stepping through the seam framework code and trying to find a datastructure to access that contains a list of parameters that have been set from the form.  Where are these things?

If I have entered a string into the hostname field of the form, the hostname parameter must be set to the value of #{searchFrom.devName}.  But how do I find out that the hostname parameter has been set?

The only alternative I can think of is to use reflection and loop through all the classes of SearchFrom and then perform introspection on the object to see which ones have been set and build my sql query from that.

There has to be a better way. Anyone know how this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done *automagically* by Seam, meaning that it **won't** add a restriction for a field of the form that has no value, so if the user only inputs data on the, for example, **devName** and **devIp** fields, then the query will be something like:

`select d from Device d where devName = ? and devIp = ?`

even if your DevicesQuery also adds 27 more restrictions for all the fields, they won't be added to the query because they are empty

Comment: I am familiar with this.  The difficulty I have is that I need to accomodate search fields from 10 different tables.  These tables can all be joined ultimately, but some are so far removed from the main search table that I cannot use the usual seam restrictions to set the where clause.  For instance a restriction like this " devices.office.siteCodeMap.siteCode = #{searchForm.sitecode} " throws an exception (I forget which one).

Comment: I wanted to manually add "where s.siteCode = #{searchForm.siteCode}" to a sql query if searchForm.siteCode is not null. Turns out that is not how EntityQuery works. It does not check all your objects for non-null-ness. Instead, it loops through the RESTRICTIONS and checks for non-null-ness of each value binding. So I ended up doing something similar. Kind of a lot to explain here. Of course your answer is correct though it's not exactly what I was looking for. It will help other people.

Comment: feel free to share your solution!